# Add informations between a database while loop

Tags: php

Please I want to display some informations between a queried database while loop results:

```
<?php

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");
    while($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $id = $sql['id'];
        $country = $sql['country'];

        echo $id.". ".$country."<br>";

    }

?>
```

If the result is:

```
1. MALAYSIA
2. GERMANY
3. EGYPT
4. CAMEROUN
5. ITALY
6. RUSSIA
7. ENGLAND
8. ETHIOPIA
9. AUSTRIA
10. JAPAN
```

I want to add something in between the result like this:

```
1. MALAYSIA
2. GERMANY
3. EGYPT
this is an advert div(1)
4. CAMEROUN
5. ITALY
this is an advert div(2)
6. RUSSIA
7. ENGLAND
8. ETHIOPIA
9. AUSTRIA
this is an advert div(3)
10. JAPAN
```

Please is it possible?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. A simple count would work. But what is the logic of interval here? 3, 2, 4??

Comment: please how can it be done?

Comment: What pattern or logic you are following to print advert `div`s?

Comment: i also store the adverts in a database table also so I can query just one at each div in a random order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will insert ads in every third row.

```
$count    = 0;
$ad_count = 1;

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");
while($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $id = $sql['id'];
    $country = $sql['country'];

    echo $id.'. '.$country.'<br>';
    $count++;

    if ($count%3==0)
    {
    echo 'this is an advert div('.$ad_count.')<br>';
    $ad_count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$count = 1;
$advertCount = 1;
$advertArr = [3, 5, 9];
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");
while($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $id = $sql['id'];
    $country = $sql['country'];

    echo $id.". ".$country."<br>";

    if (in_array($count, $advertArr)) {
        echo "this is an advert div($advertCount++)";
    }

    $count++;
}

?>
```

Though I have not tested the above solution, but I think this will help you.